# Query not returning ProcessInstanceWorkItem records in Test class

Tags: apex, soql, unit-test, approval-process

I am trying to write a test class of a class that queries on ProcessInstanceWorkItem where status is pending and a target object is a specific object of my org when I am doing the query in query editor it works well and returns the records but in the test class it is not returning the records

```
SELECT ActorId, CreatedDate, Id, ProcessInstance.ProcessDefinition.Name, ProcessInstance.SubmittedBy.Name, ProcessInstance.SubmittedById, ProcessInstance.TargetObject.Name, ProcessInstance.TargetObjectId, ProcessInstanceId FROM ProcessInstanceWorkitem WHERE ProcessInstance.Status = 'Pending'  AND ProcessInstance.TargetObject.type = 'WHT_Document__c' AND ProcessInstance.ProcessDefinition.Name IN ('Document Approval Process', 'Document Approval Process - Doc Control', 'Document Approval Process - Service', 'Document Approval Process - Submission')  AND ActorId = '0051n000007t4iVAAQ' ORDER BY CreatedDate DESC NULLS FIRST  LIMIT 49000
```

This is the query that works well in the query editor and in the test class it doesn't and I am not creating any Approval Process in the Test class as they are already in the ORG.

Answer (score 0):

In unit tests, you are responsible for creating *all* of the data that your test needs to run. Tests are isolated from the "real" data in your org by default (and that's a good thing!). The exception to that are [the "setup" objects](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api_tooling.meta/api_tooling/reference_objects_setup.htm) like `User`, `RecordType`, `Profile`, etc...

`ProcessInstance`, `ProcessInstanceWorkItem`, etc... are not setup objects. You will need to:

- Create the record (and all of the supporting records it needs for it to be created, if any)
- Submit the record to your process [using the Process* classes](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_process.htm)

Only then will you be able to get a result from your `ProcessInstanceWorkItem` query in a test.